# Java Future multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to use a future multi threading but I've an error : "cannot convert from Future to Future" when I call the executor.submit(callable).

```
package metier;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.closure.Future;

public class ScraperPages {

private String search;
private String location;
private List<Resultat> resultats;
private List<String> urls;

public ScraperPages(String search, String location) {
    this.search = search;
    this.location = location;
    this.resultats = new ArrayList<Resultat>();
}

public void getUrls() {

    String urlForPage = "https://www.pagesjaunes.fr/recherche/" + this.location + "/" + this.search;
    String urlForInfos = "https://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/chercherlespros?quoiqui=" + this.search + "&ou="
            + this.location + "&page=";
    urls = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlForPage).userAgent("Mozilla").ignoreHttpErrors(true).timeout(10000).get();
        Elements divResult = doc.getElementsByClass("pagination-compteur");
        int index = divResult.text().indexOf("/");
        int nbPage = Integer.parseInt(divResult.text().substring(index + 2));
        for (int i = 1; i < nbPage + 1; i++) {
            urls.add(urlForInfos + i);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void ScrapUrls() throws InterruptedException {
    Iterator<String> urlsIterator = urls.iterator();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Map<Future, String> tasks = new LinkedHashMap<Future, String>();

    while (urlsIterator.hasNext()) {
        String urlstr = urlsIterator.next();
        Callable<Resultat> callable = new Callable<Resultat>() {
            public Resultat call() throws Exception {
                return scrapeIndividualURL(urlstr);
            }
        };
        Future future = executor.submit(callable);
        tasks.put(future, urlstr);
    }
     tasks.forEach((future, url) -> {
             String content = future.toString();
    });
    executor.shutdown();
}

public static Resultat scrapeIndividualURL(String urlstr) {
    Resultat result = null;
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlstr).userAgent("Mozilla").ignoreHttpErrors(true).timeout(10000).get();
        Elements divResult = doc.getElementsByClass("zone-bi");
        for (Element e : divResult) {
            if (e.getElementsByClass("denomination-links").size() != 0) {
                String nom = e.getElementsByClass("denomination-links").get(0).text();
                String adresse = e.getElementsByClass("adresse-container").get(0).getElementsByClass("adresse")
                        .text();
                Elements mainContactDiv = e.getElementsByClass("main-contact-container");
                String phone = "";
                String cellphone = "";
                for (Element el : mainContactDiv) {
                    if (el.getElementsByClass("tel-zone").size() != 0) {
                        Elements telZoneDiv = el.getElementsByClass("tel-zone");
                        for (Element ele : telZoneDiv) {
                            Elements test = ele.children();
                            for (int j = 0; j < test.size(); j++) {
                                if (j != 0) {
                                    if (test.get(j - 1).text().equals(" Tél :")) {
                                        phone = test.get(j).attr("title").toString();
                                    }
                                    if (test.get(j - 1).text().equals(" Mobile :")) {
                                        cellphone = test.get(j).attr("title").toString();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                result =new Resultat(nom,adresse,phone,cellphone);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * @return the search
 */
public String getSearch() {
    return search;
}

/**
 * @param search the search to set
 */
public void setSearch(String search) {
    this.search = search;
}

/**
 * @return the location
 */
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

/**
 * @param location the location to set
 */
public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

/**
 * @return the resultats
 */
public List<Resultat> getResultats() {
    return resultats;
}

/**
 * @param resultats the resultats to set
 */
public void setResultats(List<Resultat> resultats) {
    this.resultats = resultats;
}

/**
 * @param urls the urls to set
 */
public void setUrls(List<String> urls) {
    this.urls = urls;
}
```

}

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Could you help me?

Comment: `import com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.closure.Future;` - wrong Future I think.

Comment: I think Joe's right. Watch out which import the IDE picks for you. If there's more than 1 class with the same name, it sometimes picks a weird class instead.

Comment: oh yes that's right! Too stupid. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Beyond that: read about clean code:especially the single layer of abstraction principle. Your code could benefit from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace

```
import com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.closure.Future;
```

with

```
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
```